# How to show travel history for Canadian visa

Tags: visas, canada, applications

I am applying for a Canadian visa. I would like to know how to provide a travel history document. Is there a specific template for the same. I have many stamps and visas in the passport, Do I need to provide information such as  Visa details, a country that issued it, entry/exit dates for each visit, the purpose of the visit, etc. or is it sufficient to scan all the pages and send as a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed template for the travel history document so you can draft your own. The important thing is that the information is easy to grasp and clear. You want to make the immigration officers' life easier, not harder.

[One template](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/travel-history-format-to-provide-the-same.548657/) which seems popular on the web is to make a table with specific columns:

> 6 column which support: 
>   entry date/exit date/city,country/purpose of visit/visa number

And fill it in. Then attach all the visas and stamps pages as appendixes to the table. PDF or Word documents are OK.